# Waiting for query to finish before continuing

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have this in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll
End Sub
```

All of my queries are getting updated.

I want to move some of the information a query gathers to another location. I use various ranges.

```
Sub Move_data()
    Dim rng1, rng2, rng3 As Range
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:F103")
    rng1.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A11:F111").Value

    'etc for rng2 and rng3... 
End Sub
```

The problem is that the VBA starts updating the queries, then moves the "old" data to my new location. I would like to wait until the queries are finished updating, then move the data automatically.

I can set a time-out period, but the time it takes for the query to update is very variable (between 10 sec to 2 minutes).

Also, is there a way to speed up the query-updating. I tried this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

But the query/tables/graphs are still flashing/updating. I believe this is due to the properties of Power Query, and assume I need to write something else.

Comment: Can you set the queries to update when the workbook is opened?  Then once the button is pressed, the refreshed data will be moved.

Comment: The queries that are underlying in this solution should be within the SQL category - Im assuming that you are executing SQL queries over ODBC to grab the data? is this MS Access or SQL server? We need to know how your are getting the data in your model before we can advise on query performance.

Comment: Interesting article on the speed of queries within excel: https://powerpivotpro.com/2017/07/power-query-refresh-speeds-suck/

Comment: In answer to your question around delay you can simply use some vba to implement a delay from now until a certain amount of time has passed - use:  Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#

Comment: @jimmy8ball That would be a possibility if you know how long it would take, but as the amount of time taken to run the queries changes you would have to guess the maximum amount of time it would take. I think he is looking for an answer that will detect when the queries have completed then for the code to run.

Comment: fair point, but either build a profile of run times to work out the max delay required, or look at the queries to improve speed, but  cannot advise on this until we know how data gets into the model

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to change the properties of the query so that the query does not 'Refresh in Background` - this is what's causing the macro to continue before the query has run fully.

- Go to Ribbon: [Data]
- Click on [Connections]
- Select the query you want to affect
- Press [Properties]
- Untick [Enable Background Refresh]

Now, when you run your refresh macro, execution will pause until the query has completed and the data pulled in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a table starting at cell A1.

This solution clears the contents of cell A1 and relies on the refresh to re-populate it.

A Do-While loop checks the cell A1 for content and to wait until the cell is populated.

To avoid the potential infinite loop, a counter is used to stop the loop after a number of repetitions.

```
Dim counter As Long
Dim maxcount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
maxcount = 10000
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate
' some code
ws.Cells(1,1).Clear
DoEvents

' Refresh statement
ws.ListObjects(1).Refresh

' Wait for refresh or timer to expire
Do While ws.Cells(1,1).value = ""
  Application.Wait(100)
  counter = counter + 100
  If counter >= maxcount then
    MsgBox "Refresh failed"
    End
  End If
Loop
DoEvents
```